# Changing Python Interpreter in Spyder resulting in IPython Console not loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, python-3.9, python-3.11

My current Anaconda installation comes with Python 3.11.3, but I want to change to another version of Python 3.9.9 that comes with an application that I'm using. However, every time that I've switched my Python interpreter to that (installed under *...\Exe\Python\python.exe*), new IPython consoles that I try to initiate will stay blank and not load at all. And yes, I can run that Python interpreter in a terminal just fine.

Other things that I have tried include:

- Adding that version of Python into the PATH variable
- Adding *...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts* and *...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages* into the PYTHONPATH variable
- Installing the latest version of spyder-kernels onto the Python 3.9 version via command prompt

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.